# parsing two-dimensional array to string in python

Tags: python, django, string, list

please help me in parsing two-dimensional array.
For example i have array :

```
arr = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3']]
```

and have loop, in them was creating the string with new one array and this one two-demensional array.

ex :

```
date = ['1 -', '2 -', '3 -']
string = ""
for i in range(len(date)):
   string = string + str(date[i]) + ...
```

how in this loop i can take string value like :

```
1 - a1,b1; 2 - a2,b2; 3 - a3,b3;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like thos:

```
>>> ' '.join('{} {};'.format(a, ','.join(b)) for a, b in zip(date, zip(*arr)))
'1 - a1,b1; 2 - a2,b2; 3 - a3,b3;'
```

Here first we transpose `arr` using zip with `*`:

```
>>> x = zip(*arr)
>>> x
[('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')]
```

Now we can zip this with date to get:

```
>>> y = zip(date, x)
>>> y
[('1 -', ('a1', 'b1')), ('2 -', ('a2', 'b2')), ('3 -', ('a3', 'b3'))]
```

Now we can simply loop through this array and perform string formatting and `str.join` operation on the items to get:

```
>>> z = ['{} {};'.format(a, ','.join(b)) for a, b in y]
>>> z
['1 - a1,b1;', '2 - a2,b2;', '3 - a3,b3;']
```

Now all we need to do is join these items using a `' '`:

```
>>> ' '.join(z)
'1 - a1,b1; 2 - a2,b2; 3 - a3,b3;'
```

Comment: thanks it's working, but question, if i have not two, but few array's in "arr", and them was change every time.

Comment: exaple, when i put in script other date i have :
arr = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]